# I'm using macOS Big Sur and installed successfully mongoldb version 5.0 but cannot connect Node.js App to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**When I try to start mongoldb from hyper terminal this message pops up:**

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ mongod --dbpath=/data
“mongod” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
Killed: 9
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ mongod

“mongod” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
Killed: 9
```

**I cannot Connect to MongoDB**

following the initial structure 'mkdir' & 'npm init', I created a new app.js
and tried to run the 'node app.js' from hyper terminal after starting the mongoldb:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew services start  mongodb-community@5.0

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@5.0` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@5.0)
```

The hyper terminal does not return anything just shows a curser in command line as it is on.

**I'm using macOS Big Sur **

the terminal also returns :

```
**hyper terminal and used commands:**
dmins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew services list
Name                  Status  User  File
mongodb-community@5.0 started admin ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@5.0.plist
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew services stop  mongodb-community@5.0
Stopping `mongodb-community@5.0`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community@5.0` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@5.0)
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew services start  mongodb-community@5.0
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community@5.0` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@5.0)
```

When I open macOS terminal line **command not found** is there:
**command not found**

```
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log.
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log.
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod
zsh: command not found: mongod
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongo --version
zsh: command not found: mongo
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod
zsh: command not found: mongod
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Any hint to solve this problem is appreciated.

**MongoDB is not connecting to node.js **
**my app.js in atom is:**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    client.close();
  });
});

const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {a : 1},
    {a : 2},
    {a : 3}
  ], function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
    console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: It says "Successfully started `mongodb-community@5.0", so everything should be fine. What is the error you get?

Comment: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
    at process.wrappedCwd [as cwd] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126:28)
    at node:path:1082:24
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1096:39)
    at resolveMainPath (node:internal/modules/run_main:19:40)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:75:24)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'uv_cwd'
}. 

The above comes from macOs terminal but in the hyper terminal it runs without any indication of established connection

Comment: The erro pops up from macOs terminal when I try to run the 'node app.js' to add a new database element into existing database schema.       
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro Desktop % cd fruitPoject/
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro fruitPoject % node app.js
I was expecting any alert for successful connection node.js and mongo db but cannot see any. However, the connection is working properly
test> show dbs
admin      40.00 KiB
config     36.00 KiB
fruitsDB  192.00 KiB
local      72.00 KiB
test> use fruitsDB
switched to db fruitsDB
fruitsDB> show collections

Comment: Please edit your question for such additional information. And please focus on what is **not** working, your question is way too long.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to solve only one of your problems.

1. Close the error message dialog if it's open.
2. Open "System Preferences" on your Mac.
3. Click on "Security & Privacy."
4. In the "General" tab, you should see a message mentioning that "mongod" was blocked. Below that, you will see an "Open Anyway" button. Click on it.
   A confirmation dialog will appear, asking if you want to open the application. Click "Open" to proceed.
5. macOS will then open "mongod," and you should be able to use it.

Comment: For some reason, doing that doesn't work for me. I am on a company mac so perhaps that is why?. Do you know of any other approaches/workarounds?